# Return different amounts of each varible in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query like

```
MATCH (first:Book {ISBN: {ISBN}})-[:IN]-(category:BookCategory)-[:IN]-(books:Book)
RETURN *
```

Basically it gets a book by its ISBN (provided in a parameter), finds a category it's in, and finds other books in that category.

I would like it to only return 1 `:BookCategory`, but unlimited books in that category. For example, *War and Peace* is categorized under *Classics* **and** *War Novels*. Running this query on *War and Peace* returns *War and Peace*, *Classics*, *War Novels*, and all the books in both categories. I would like to instead return all the books in *Classics* **or** *War Novels* (I don't care which), and *Classics* **or** *War Novels* itself. The result might look like:

```
==================================================
 first         | category | books                |
===============|==========|=======================
 War and Peace | Classics | Old Yeller           |
===============|==========|=======================
                          | Anne of Green Gables |
                          |=======================
                          |         ...          |
```

In short I want a way to `limit` the amount of some variables but not others. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just limit your query at the category level and then continue :

```
MATCH (first:Book {ISBN: {ISBN}})-[:IN]-(category:BookCategory)
WITH first, category
LIMIT 1 
MATCH (category)-[:IN]-(books:Book)
WHERE books <> first
RETURN first, category, collect(books) as books
```

Limit books to 50 :

```
MATCH (first:Book {ISBN: {ISBN}})-[:IN]-(category:BookCategory)
WITH first, category
LIMIT 1 
MATCH (category)-[:IN]-(books:Book)
WHERE books <> first
RETURN first, category, collect(books)[0..50] as books
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great! But how can I limit the amount of books to say, 50, to stop 10000 war novels from being sent to the user?

Comment: added in the answer